# Print the column data of a data frame based on the condition on consecutive numbers

Tags: python, dataframe, multiple-occurrence

I would like to print all the columns data from the below data where the consecutive values should be (for 14 continuous minutes or longer). it means (1,2,.....14) will definitely come and if I have these consecutive values means greater than 14 like this (1,2,3,....20), this output should also come from the consecutive column.

The condition is ID and date should be same for those consecutive numbers.

```
ID    DATE            TIME        start end consecutive
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:20   7   20  1
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:21   7   21  2
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:23   7   23  1
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:24   7   24  2
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:25   7   25  3
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:26   7   26  4
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:27   7   27  5
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:29   7   29  1
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:30   7   30  2
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:31   7   31  3
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:32   7   32  4
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:33   7   33  5
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:34   7   34  6
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:35   7   35  7
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:36   7   36  8
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:37   7   37  9
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:38   7   38  10
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:39   7   39  11
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:40   7   40  12
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:41   7   41  13
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:42   7   42  14
456 8/15/2015 0:00  8/15/2015 9:52  9   52  1
456 8/15/2015 0:00  8/15/2015 9:56  9   56  3
456 8/15/2015 0:00  8/15/2015 10:10 15  17  1
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:18 15  18  2
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:34 15  34  1
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:35 15  35  2
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:36 15  36  3
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:37 15  37  4
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:38 15  38  5
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:39 15  39  6
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:40 15  40  7
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:41 15  41  8
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:42 15  42  9
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:43 15  43  10
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:44 15  44  11
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:45 15  45  12
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:46 15  46  13
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:47 15  47  14
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:48 15  48  15
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:49 15  49  16
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:50 15  50  17
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:51 15  51  18
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:52 15  52  19
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:53 15  53  20
```

My Expected Output is:

```
ID    DATE                TIME   start  end consecutive
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:29   7   29  1
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:30   7   30  2
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:31   7   31  3
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:32   7   32  4
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:33   7   33  5
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:34   7   34  6
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:35   7   35  7
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:36   7   36  8
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:37   7   37  9
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:38   7   38  10
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:39   7   39  11
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:40   7   40  12
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:41   7   41  13
123 1/5/2016 0:00   1/5/2016 7:42   7   42  14
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:34 15  34  1
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:35 15  35  2
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:36 15  36  3
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:37 15  37  4
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:38 15  38  5
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:39 15  39  6
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:40 15  40  7
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:41 15  41  8
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:42 15  42  9
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:43 15  43  10
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:44 15  44  11
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:45 15  45  12
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:46 15  46  13
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:47 15  47  14
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:48 15  48  15
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:49 15  49  16
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:50 15  50  17
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:51 15  51  18
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:52 15  52  19
456 5/21/2015 0:00  5/21/2015 15:53 15  53  20
```

Comment: You saying `consecutive values > = 14` ...Where these `15,16,17,18,19,20` values coming from in expected output?

Comment: consecutive values should be for 14 continuous minutes or longer. it means (1,2,.....14) will definitely come and if I have (1,2,3,....20), this output should also come.